# WFFM Checkbox value is always false

Tags: wffm, fieldtype

We have a WFFM form on Sitecore 8.1 rev 160523, with a custom save action where we want to store the form data as a Sitecore item.

When we try to retrieve the value of a checkbox, we always get *False*. The checkbox is default WFFM.

This is how we get the value:

```
adaptedFields.GetEntryByID(fieldId).Value
```

When we check the post values in Fiddler we see the following:

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryvNC5aqyb3BnVxz0V
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="wffm538c1e5743a34e1c86f9c4ea9a7557ba.Sections[3].Fields[0].{E8252991-D75B-4479-8FDB-4DCD72BA35FA}"

true

------WebKitFormBoundaryvNC5aqyb3BnVxz0V    
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="wffm538c1e5743a34e1c86f9c4ea9a7557ba.Sections[3].Fields[0].{E8252991-D75B-4479-8FDB-4DCD72BA35FA}"
false
```

Does anyone have an idea how to solve this?